# iOS ionic app status bar rotation issue

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have an issue in my Ionic 1.x app with the iOS status bar rotating in an undesirable way.

I want the app to only allow portrait view and to do that I added the following line: `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` to my root `config.xml` file.

This works fine, however, when the phone is held in a landscape position, the app view stays in portrait mode, but the status bar of the iOS device rotates to landscape mode. A user fix of course is to just lock their phone to portrait orientation, but not everyone does that.

**Portrait View**

[image]

**Landscape View**

[image]

Does anyone know why it is acting this way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct settings in Xcode (Device Orientation and Status Bar Style).

[Click here to open the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r8aR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "UIMainStoryboardFile" from your plist file.